# Scraping financial data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape financial data from Yahoo Finance using R, but haven't been able to succeed. You can see my current code below. The main problem seems to be that the table storing the financial data in Yahoo Finance is not modelled as a table in the HTML code there. How can I bypass this problem?

I have already tried to copy the Xpath that seems to contain the table with no luck.

```
library(XML)

symbol = "HD"
url <- paste('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/HD/financials?p=',symbol,sep="")
webpage <- readLines(url)
html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table")

data <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with yahoo finance, you are doing a minor mistake, as the `tableNodes` can contain more than one table so use the below to get all tables :

```
library(XML)

symbol = "HD"
url <- paste('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/HD/analysts?p=',symbol,sep="")
webpage <- readLines(url)
html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table")

earningsEstimates <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]])
revenueEstimates <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[2]])
earningsHistory <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[3]])
earningPerShareTrend <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[4]])
earningPerShareRevision <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[5]])
growthEstimates <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[6]])

print(earningsEstimates) # printing one table
```

output

```
 Earnings Estimate Current Qtr. (Oct 2019) Next Qtr. (Jan 2020) Current Year (2020)
1   No. of Analysts                      28                   28                  35
2     Avg. Estimate                    2.52                 2.17               10.13
3      Low Estimate                    2.47                 2.07               10.03
4     High Estimate                    2.58                 2.24               10.27
5      Year Ago EPS                    2.51                 2.25                9.89
  Next Year (2021)
1               35
2            10.96
3             10.7
4             11.2
5            10.13
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. However, I am not interested in the Analyst part of Yahoo Finance, but rather the Finances part, for which I believe the html elements are not called table, but <div something>. How can I change my code to account for this?